# Unable to create image using Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I need to generalize and capture a linux virtual machine.

I deployed the VM using ARM template. In ARM template, I used the following to get VHD stored in storage account

```
            "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
                    "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
                    "sku": "[variables('imageSku')]",
                    "version": "latest"
                },
                "osDisk": {
                    "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                    "createOption": "fromImage",
                    "vhd": {
                        "uri": "[concat(concat(reference(resourceId(variables('resourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob'], 'vhds/'), parameters('virtualMachineName'), concat(uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '.vhd'))]"
                    }
                },
                "dataDisks": []
            },
```

Now I am following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image) to create and image and VM.

When I execute the following command, I am getting error

```
az image create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myImage --source myVM

The storage account containing blob https://testvmstorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/testvmyrg5wfer6xbcg.vhd is or has been encrypted. Copy the blob to an unencrypted storage account before importing.
```

Comment: why don't you do what it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your storage account is encryption, you will get the error log. You could check it on Azure Portal.
[image]

Now, if you want to the VHD to create a image, you need create a non-encryption account and copy the VHD to it. You could use Azcopy to copy VHDs between containers. Just an example below:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://shuidisks446.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Dest:https://shuidiag102.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceKey:sGqtdFHQWQWYyf2tRWGF5jkeAEubTp13AVaeTM25QogxXE+K0Ezq1ulcs18qGVPhCEp6ULdLLbKVa7fMbUvYZg== /DestKey:iCjeS+eegjkSJXHjH2UqCkqXnUPiCGvxaOG0Ad2LoPgUnvBoWl9wQJtC1jc//lOj4CF7khpLQe791P4QeyTY6Q== /Pattern:shui20161222141315.vhd
```

After the VHD transfers to new storage account, you could use the VHD to create a snapshot, then use the snapshot to create image.

Note: You could not create image with VHD directly.

You could use the following commands.

```
az snapshot create -g shui2 -n shuisna --source https://shui2.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/shui20170607110945.vhd
az image create -g shui2 -n shuiimage --source shuisna --os-type linux
```